# How to add pre-made text to a form with a button click from another page? Wordpress Elementor

Tags: wordpress, button, elementor, formidable

I have a home accomodation website and it has a page with all the rooms and another one with contact info and email form. The page with rooms has a "Book" button under every room. My idea was that when the "Book" button is pushed than the wepage automatically goes to the Contact page and room info is submitted to the email form. For example when i press the Book button under 3-people bedroom than the text "The client likes to book 3-people bedroom" is added to the email form. I am using Wordpress and Elementor builder for my page and Formidable for form.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could even do this simpler then the suggestion of Umair by indeed adding a parameter to the url.  But then istead of using the echo, you can easily retrieve the values by adding the following code as default value in the form [get param=parameter]

So in your example you would create three buttons with following url

```
https://example.org/contact?room=room1
https://example.org/contact?room=room2
https://example.org/contact?room=room3
```

On your contact form choose the field in which you want to show the text and add as default value

```
[get param=room].
```

Obviously you can change the text after the parameter 'room=' in whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Yes you need to add a get request url (https://testdomain.com/formpage/?formtext=formtitle) of this button so when the user click on the button it will redirect with the get request url like this https://testdomain.com/formpage/?formtext=formtitle

then you can add this variable echo where ever you want to display this text also in the fomidable form also have this variable option to place in form.
so your form will be display with the selected text by default.

```
if( $_GET["formtext"]){
 echo $_GET["formtext"];
}
```